# security - Process.execute() on android

Tags: android, security, process, execute

Given i have compiled linux exe file in my resources/raw directory.
Can i execute it using Process.execute("./resources/raw/filename") or i have to have special permissions (like ROOT or smth) ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, How did you compile the executable? I hope you've used a Cross-Compiler.

And Yes, you can execute applications...No special rights required.

I haven't tried that method, (`Process.execute()`) But i can Confirm `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/a.out");` works.... :)

When you execute it, the application will have the same privilege level as your application (non-root)...unless you rooted the device.

Comment: i meant 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec' of course. It is possible to use adb and push file and set its mode (via chmod) as needed.Is it possible to set necessary permissions or change owner or group to make him allowed to read /dev/graphics/fb0 f.e.?

Comment: well, yes, but that'll work only on your emulator...on a device, you can't (...again, unless its rooted)